# How to fix cutting corner problem in a star

Tags: a-star

Im trying to implement a* path-finding for my 3d game

I have implemented it and it works

But there is that cutting corner problem

[image]

This is when doing  diagonal jumps (checking diagonal neighbor nodes).
In 2d it can be prevented by doing some checks, like if up and right is blocked, don't take up-right neighbour for calculations, 
but in 3d thous check become a bit to much and to tedious.. so if I still want diagonal paths, what could be a smart solution?

Comment: Hey! Good question you have there, I see this problem in many games. However on Stack Overflow there is an expectancy that you provide some code showing your issue (see [mcve]). I think your question might find a better home on our sister site [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), you can ask your question there and get answers from video game dev experts. Make sure to read their [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help). Hope you get an answer to your question!

Comment: Question is more theoretical. Sharing code here would make no much point. And I will post on GameDev. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I get it, the thing is that while theoretical questions are welcome on Stack Overflow, you're much more likely to get a good answer from specialized sites.